# converting SQL double in String

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, linq

I am getting a problem when fetching double value from using linq and converting it into string. My code is:-

```
 public List<ShowDataOnClient> GetCardListToShow()
    {
        try
        {
            List<ShowDataOnClient> CardList = new List<ShowDataOnClient>();
            using (ProgressCardLINQDataContext c = new ProgressCardLINQDataContext())
            {
                CardList = (from card in c.GetTable<T_PROGRESSCARD>()
                            where card.RecordStatus.Equals(RecordStatus.Active)
                            select new ShowDataOnClient
                            {
                                Student=(from student in c.T_STUDENTs
                                         where student.Id.Equals(card.StudentId)
                                         select student.Name).Single().ToString(),
                                Test=(from test in c.T_TESTs
                                      where test.Id.Equals(card.TestId)
                                      select test.Name).Single().ToString(),
                                MaxMarks = (from test in c.T_TESTs
                                            where test.Id.Equals(card.TestId)
                                            select test.MaxMarks).Single().ToString(),
                                MarksObtain=card.MarksObtain.ToString(),
                                Percentage=card.Percentage.ToString()

                            }).ToList<ShowDataOnClient>();
            }
            return CardList;
        }
        catch
        {
            return new List<ShowDataOnClient>();
        }
    }
```

I have tried this also:-

```
 Percentage=Math.Truncate(card.Percentage).ToString()
```

and when i pass "N2" in ToString it gives exception "Method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL."

and the value i got after conversion is like this:- 5.200000000000000e+001

is there anybody to help me..

Comment: What is the value of `Percentage`? Are you trying to do this in _SQL_? SQL doesn't have a `ToString` method.

Comment: you can convert it to ToList() or ToArray() to get the values.

Comment: What is card.Percentage?

Comment: Percentage is string, card.Percentage is double and I am doing this using Linq to SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Your `ShowDataOnClient` class should store the value of `Percentage` as a `double`. You can format the way doubles are presented to the user at a later stage. How you do that depends on the control you're using to show the data.

This has the added benefit that sorting functions would work as expected. If you convert your percentage to string this early, sorting by that column won't look right

```
% as String     % as double
1%              1%
10%             2%
11%             10%
2%              11%
23%             23%
etc.            etc.
```

Comment: +1 this is a better solution. As Alex says, change `ShowDataOnClient.Percentage' to a double

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
double Percentage = card.Percentage;

string PercentageStr = Percentage.ToString();
```

This will not invoke linq to sql and give you what you want.